# react native:0.62, Xcode13 react-native run-ios build failed

Tags: ios, react-native, macos

Kind of New to react-native, and therefore I am not really experienced with native codes such as iOS (Objective-c) and Android (Java).

Old legacy React Native was given to me with the version of 0.62, whereas my mac is silicon M1 with os of 12.2.1 (Monterey), and Xcode with version 13.1.

**Summary**

- React Native: 0.62.0
- MacOS: 12.2.1 (monterey) M1
- Xcode: 13.1

I probably tried every content that can be found in the web (google search, youtube search).

My question is, *Is it possible to run iOS with the above setting?*

FYI, the Android build was successful.

Error:

> ** BUILD FAILED ** The following build commands failed: CompileC /Users/moon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hk_homepage_app-btbndomnvsxxjsfhvjmjjeibfefe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RCTCxxBridge.o
> /try2//node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm
> normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (in target 'React-Core' from project 'Pods') (1 failure)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error you encountered?

Comment: ** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/moon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hk_homepage_app-btbndomnvsxxjsfhvjmjjeibfefe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RCTCxxBridge.o /try2/<packagename>/node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-Core' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
something like this error but with many different version

Comment: Helped you put the error in your question. Read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32707)